# Efficient way to execute udf based on group

Tags: performance, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am new to pyspark and have a performance issue. Given a dataframe

```
| Group | Id   |  Selected |
| ----- | ---- | --------- |
|   A   |  id1 |      0    |
|   A   |  id2 |      0    |
|   A   |  id3 |      0    |
|   B   |  id4 |      0    |
|   B   |  id5 |      0    |
```

And a sampling dictionary

```py
sample_dict = {'A': 2, 'B': 1}
```

I want to randomly select (update the Selected column) of the dataframe follows the sampling dictionary. For example

```
| Group |  Id  |  Selected |
| ----- | ---- | --------- |
|   A   |  id1 |     *1*   |
|   A   |  id2 |      0    |
|   A   |  id3 |     *1*   |
|   B   |  id4 |      0    |
|   B   |  id5 |     *1*   |
```

Currently, I can only iterate through each group, get the subgroup, randomly select Id and update the original dataframe according to the Ids

```py
for group in sample_dict:
  sub_df = df.filter(col('Group') == group)
  # id_list = a_udf_randomly_sample_n_Id_from_sub_df
  # update df['Selected'] if df['Id'].isin(id_list)
```

The problem with this approach is sequential processing (do each group one-by-one). If the number of group and total rows scale up, the pyspark code runs slower than the simple pandas version (on databricks).

Would you share better approaches (e.g. processing the incident selection in each group in parallel) for this problem in pyspark?

Thank you very much

Comment: I don't really get the logic of your example output. Why did you change the values of the 1. 3. and 5. row to *1*? The 5. row is of group B while the 1. and 3. row is of group A. Can try to explain it a bit more?

Comment: for each group g, I want to randomly pick n_g records (to simplify the logic, I omit other criteria and only pick randomly). Given 'A': 2, I want to pick 2 records from group A. As an example, Id 1 and 3 was selected randomly and I updated the Selected column accordingly.